# How to give a div a higher z-index on click with JS?

Tags: javascript

I asked this question yesterday hopefully this one is clearer as I've now provided a working example of my store.

I'm developing a Shopify Theme. I've been using [Timber](https://github.com/Shopify/Timber) as my base and I'm currently having a problem with my Quick Cart and Quick Shop/View drawers.

I have 2 drawers on the right of my site, 1 for the cart and 1 for the product quick view option. The drawers currently slide open - #PageContainer moves to the left on click to reveal each drawer.

As they are currently sitting on top of each other I need to alter the JS so that on click the z-index changes so that the correct drawer being called is highest in the stack.

I'm not great with JS so not sure if this is a simple task?

Here is a link to my [Dev Store](http://test-store-980.myshopify.com)

JS:

```
timber.Drawers = (function () {
var Drawer = function (id, position, options) {
var defaults = {
  close: '.js-drawer-close',
  open: '.js-drawer-open-' + position,
  openClass: 'js-drawer-open',
  dirOpenClass: 'js-drawer-open-' + position
};

this.$nodes = {
  parent: $('body, html'),
  page: $('#PageContainer'),
  moved: $('.is-moved-by-drawer')
};

this.config = $.extend(defaults, options);
this.position = position;

this.$drawer = $('#' + id);

if (!this.$drawer.length) {
  return false;
}

this.drawerIsOpen = false;
this.init();
};

Drawer.prototype.init = function () {
$(this.config.open).on('click', $.proxy(this.open, this));
this.$drawer.find(this.config.close).on('click', $.proxy(this.close,     this));
};

Drawer.prototype.open = function (evt) {
// Keep track if drawer was opened from a click, or called by another  function
var externalCall = false;

// Prevent following href if link is clicked
if (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
} else {
  externalCall = true;
}

// Without this, the drawer opens, the click event bubbles up to     $nodes.page
// which closes the drawer.
if (evt && evt.stopPropagation) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  // save the source of the click, we'll focus to this on close
  this.$activeSource = $(evt.currentTarget);
}

if (this.drawerIsOpen && !externalCall) {
  return this.close();
}

// Add is-transitioning class to moved elements on open so drawer can  have
// transition for close animation
this.$nodes.moved.addClass('is-transitioning');
this.$drawer.prepareTransition();

this.$nodes.parent.addClass(this.config.openClass + ' ' +     this.config.dirOpenClass);
this.drawerIsOpen = true;

// Run function when draw opens if set
if (this.config.onDrawerOpen && typeof(this.config.onDrawerOpen) ==    'function') {
  if (!externalCall) {
    this.config.onDrawerOpen();
  }
}

if (this.$activeSource && this.$activeSource.attr('aria-expanded')) {
  this.$activeSource.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
}

// Lock scrolling on mobile
this.$nodes.page.on('touchmove.drawer', function () {
 return false;
});

this.$nodes.page.on('click.drawer', $.proxy(function () {
 this.close();
 return false;
}, this));
};

Drawer.prototype.close = function () {
if (!this.drawerIsOpen) { // don't close a closed drawer
 return;
}

// deselect any focused form elements
$(document.activeElement).trigger('blur');

// Ensure closing transition is applied to moved elements, like the nav
this.$nodes.moved.prepareTransition({ disableExisting: true });
this.$drawer.prepareTransition({ disableExisting: true });

this.$nodes.parent.removeClass(this.config.dirOpenClass + ' ' +     this.config.openClass);

this.drawerIsOpen = false;

this.$nodes.page.off('.drawer');
};
return Drawer;
})();
```

**Update**

As instructed by Ciprian I have placed the following in my JS which is making the #CartDrawer have a higher z-index. I'm now unsure how I adapt this so that it knows which one to have higher dependant on which button is clicked. This is what I've tried:

```
...

Drawer.prototype.init = function () {
$(this.config.open).on('click', $.proxy(this.open, this));

$('.js-drawer-open-right-two').click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

if($('.js-drawer-open-right-two').data('clicked')) {
  //clicked element, do-some-stuff
  $('#QuickShopDrawer').css('z-index', '999');
} else {
  //run function 2
  $('#CartDrawer').css('z-index', '999');
}

this.$drawer.find(this.config.close).on('click', $.proxy(this.close, this));
};

...
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach would be like this:

```
$('.yourselector').css('z-index', '999');
```

Add it (and adapt it to your needs) inside your `onclick()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I understand what you're saying but as the JS comes with Timber I'm not sure where I need to place this in my current JS. Should I be adapting this part?... 'Drawer.prototype.init = function () {
$(this.config.open).on('click', $.proxy...'

Comment: I think under this line: `this.$nodes.page.on('click.drawer', $.proxy(function () {`

Comment: @Ciprian, You missed an apostrophe after 999.

Comment: Is '.yourselector' the button that triggers the drawer to open? Or is it the div containing the content I want to display? Also is `this.$nodes.page.on('click.drawer', $.proxy(function () {` not to do with closing the drawer?

Comment: You should change `.yourselector` to the button that triggers the drawer to open/close. Also, try adding that line to each of your `onclick()` functions. I don't know how your code works.

Comment: Ok so I've put `$('#CartDrawer').css('z-index', '999');` in and after a couple of clicks its showing the contents of the cart. How would it know to switch between the two?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to modify the z-index of your div when clicking a buton, you shoud put in this code on your onclick() function, else if you need to activate it when you looding the page you shoud put it on a $( document ).ready() function , the code is :

```
$('#yourID').css('z-index', '10');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("your-element-id").style.zIndex = 5;
```

It's pure Javascript and sets the z-index to 5. Just bind this to onClick event!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I understand that this needs to be applied to the click event but as I'm not great with JS I'm just not sure which part of my current code I should rewrite or how.

Comment: @user2498890, What is the selector of the element you want to bind the click to ? What is the selector of the element you want to change the z-index ?

Comment: He is using jQuery, so this solution is not appropriate.

Comment: @Ciprian, If you use jQuery, it doesn't mean you can't use pure Javascript which is always faster :)

Comment: So I have 2 drawers sat on top of each other one is #QuickShopDrawer and the other #CartDrawer - on click of 'Cart' and 'Add to Cart' the cart drawer is opened and on click of 'Buy' the quick shop is opened.