# Alternate z-index between 2 divs on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not great with JS so been using trial and error to try and figure out how to get 2 divs to swap z-index on the click of a trigger (button).

I currently have 2 drawers that technically are on top of each other and slide out from the right. On click of 'Buy' the #QuickShopDrawer should open and on click of 'Cart' or 'Add to Cart' the #CartDrawer should open.

Link to my [test store](http://test-store-980.myshopify.com).

My code so far is making the open with the #CartDrawer on top with a higher z-index.

JS:

```
Drawer.prototype.init = function () {
$(this.config.open).on('click', $.proxy(this.open, this));

$('.js-drawer-open-right-two').click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

if($('.js-drawer-open-right-two').data('clicked')) {
  //clicked element, do-some-stuff
  $('#QuickShopDrawer').css('z-index', '999');
} else {
  //run function 2
  $('#CartDrawer').css('z-index', '999');
}

this.$drawer.find(this.config.close).on('click', $.proxy(this.close, this));
};
```

I've tried this which is more of what I want but it's only firing once?

```
$('.js-drawer-open-right-two').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  $('.drawer--right').hide();
  $('.drawer--right-two' + (i+1)).show();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create a quick fiddle with onlt the relevant code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give a div a higher z-index on click with JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795179/how-to-give-a-div-a-higher-z-index-on-click-with-js)

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the `z-index` of the elements on button click. Also, you can `disable` the button on click so that user cannot click it continiously.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/zgnj889p/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#buy').on('click', function(e) {
    var myZindex = $('#QuickShopDrawer').css('z-index');
    $('#QuickShopDrawer').css('z-index', $('#CartDrawer').css('z-index'));
    $('#CartDrawer').css('z-index', myZindex);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true).siblings('button').prop('disabled', false);
  });

  $('#addToCart').on('click', function(e) {
    var myZindex = $('#CartDrawer').css('z-index');
    $('#CartDrawer').css('z-index', $('#QuickShopDrawer').css('z-index'));
    $('#QuickShopDrawer').css('z-index', myZindex);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true).siblings('button').prop('disabled', false);
  });

});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  clear: both;
}
#addToCart {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.red {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.green {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="QuickShopDrawer" class="red">fdsafdsafdsa</div>
  <div id="CartDrawer" class="green">fdsafdsafdsa</div>
</div>
<button id="buy">Buy</button>
<button id="addToCart">Add To Cart</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response this doesn't seem to be working any ideas why?

Comment: Update answer to use your `selectors`.

Comment: I did do that but not having any luck.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you think this means that my selectors must be wrong?

Comment: Yes, update accordingly your `selectors` e.g. `.js-drawer-open-right-two`

Comment: When you click the same button twice it toggles the z-index, and I don't think the OP wants that. Clicking Buy should always bring the same div to the forefront, not toggle it. Effectively, both buttons are doing the same thing.

Comment: I have managed to get it to work but I think Danny is describing exactly what is happening its happening on second click. How do I avoid this? I'll update my test store so you can see.

Comment: It still seems to be glitchy and switching between the two. https://test-store-980.myshopify.com